# Algorithm to find trinary code for given alphabet

Tags: algorithms, optimization, huffman-coding

A friend sent me this question and I've been stuck on it so if anyone could help I'll be thankful.

Reminder: As we know Huffman coding is a lossless data compression algorithm. The most frequent character $\sigma \in \Sigma$ gets the smallest code and the least frequent character gets the largest code. The variable-length codes assigned to input characters are prefix codes.

Question: Our task is to find Trinary code that satisfies the same purpose. In other words, a trinary code $c$ is a function $c:\Sigma \rightarrow (0,\ 1,\ 2)^*$. We call this code a prefix-less if for every $\sigma_1 \in \Sigma$ and $\sigma_2 \in \Sigma$ where $\sigma_1 \neq \sigma_2$, $\sigma_1$ isn't prefix of $\sigma_2$, and $\sigma_2$ isn't a prefix of $\sigma_1$.

We need to find an algorithm that for given frequencies $f_{\sigma}\geq0$ for every $\sigma \in \Sigma$, finds a trinary code $c$ that is prefix-less that gives us optimized code like that of Huffman code. In other words, it optimizes the sum: $$\sum_{\sigma \in \Sigma} f_{\sigma}\cdot |c(\sigma)|$$

I tried to do something like Huffman coding such that taking every time the lowest 3 frequencies every time and merging them to be one vertex but it didn't work, it's true that I got prefix-less code but it's not optimized.

A more complicated but wrong solution that I tried is to take every time the highest two frequencies, merge them, and then for the third one we check if there is more than 1 leaf left, if so we merge it too, if not we create it as a new vertex with no frequency.

So I don't really know what to do in order to get such an optimal trinary code.

Comment: Answered on Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding#n-ary_Huffman_coding

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Thank you I found the solution in youtube too.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP managed to solve it on their own.